# Crontab skipping pg_restore if archive has sql errors

Tags: linux, postgresql, cron

I have a strange problem with cron which is skipping pg_restore command (Postgres Restore) in the script file and not reporting any errors in the log file even if stderr is enabled. Could any one help what I am doing wrong?

**Update:**
Added Distribution Info and Cron,

I am using CentOS release 5.4 (Final) distribution with 64 bit package and my cron job is,

```
51 14 * * * /opt/scripts/test.sh 2>&1  >> /opt/logs/test.txt
```

**Note: This is happening if backup(*.tar) archive has any errors but restores if I run the script manually.**

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Could you provide some details (distribution, `crontab -l`, etc.) ?

Comment: I can't believe you say you have a script that doesn't work, but don't show the script. I tried my psychic debugging once more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the postgres version and the installed CentOS because I used external repository to download the latest version of postgres and learned that its always best to download the postgres version supported and verified by centos team from the same repository only.

Answer (score 1):

The odds are that you must specify the absolute, full path to the `pg_restore` command.

Since you don't seem to show your script, I cannot actually see that you forgot to.

This is a FAQ item since cron jobs run in a reduced environment and the PATH variable can be set to other things (or even be unset)

Comment: Yes I have given the full path and its working fine but I am really surprised because I have two different machines having Pgsql 8.4 installed and my first machine's script is running fine only for the 2nd machine's script I am getting problem and its working if I give full path for pg_restore.

Comment: Well, I guess I don't have to point out the obvious: there _is_ a difference! On debian, `man cron` will shed some light on the files involved. You could just compare the /etc folders between systems for a good start. Regardless, being explicit is **very** good practice in cron jobs on any distro, so perhaps you want to silence your inner Sherlock and just accept the state of affairs and learn for the future

Comment: For your information both the machines are running CentOS release 5.4 (Final) then how could there be a difference?

Comment: @Karthik: of course I can't answer that. Lesson one in diagnostics: never deny the obvious truth. How it happened? A zillion ways; I'm not sure you can always figure that out, but the question (IMHO) should be: does it matter?

Comment: I have now strange problem even if I use full path its not restoring if the archive has sql errors.

Comment: You might want to start a new question. It sounds like a reasonable thing to do, if your archive has _errors_? Probably `ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK` is set, so it will rightly avoid 'half' restores

Comment: I understand but if thats the case it should not be executed if I start the script manually right?

Comment: Perhaps you should _name_ the errors? You're not telling nearly enough (only _now_ do you mention that the script _does run_ outside crontab, e.g.). Right now I'm guessing that the LANG or TZ environment variables are different when run from crontab, or something similar to that. You really should open a new question and give some more information

Comment: Sorry I get sql errors because same schema will exists and the errors are manageable the problem is once these errors are reported pg_restore will start the copy command to restore the DB which is not working and I hope thats the root cause. The thing I found is if I manually run the script it will report sql errors and start the copy command but in cron its reporting errors but not starting the copy command. Hope this information is sufficient.